# error solving Balanced Brackets check from hacker rank using stack

Tags: c++, stack

while solving Balanced Brackets check  from hacker rank using stack, the error I am getting is :

```
Solution.cpp: In function ‘std::__cxx11::string isBalanced(std::__cxx11::string)’:
Solution.cpp:7:17: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
     stack<char> c;
                 ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
```

But it works fine on CodeChef compiler.

```
string isBalanced(string s) {
    stack<char> c;

    for(int i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(s[0]=='}' || s[0]==')' || s[0]==']')
        return "NO";
        else if(s[i]=='{' || s[i]=='(' || s[i]=='[')
        {
            c.push(s[i]);
        }
        else if((c.top()=='{' && s[i]=='}') || (c.top()=='(' && s[i]==')') || (c.top()=='[' && s[i]==']')){
            c.pop();
        } 
        else 
        return "NO";
    }
    if (c.empty())
        return "YES";
    }
```

Comment: Please always post a [mcve] that we can run ourselves, rather than incomplete code snippets.

Comment: If, at the end of the function, `c` is not in fact empty, the function reaches the closing brace and doesn't `return` anything. Whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: This your function needs to return a string, which it may not do in some sequence of conditional checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, your function does not always return a value. You could fix that by returning "NO", in the case that your `stack` is not empty at the end of the function:

```
if (c.empty())
    return "YES";
return "NO";
```

Note that the return value of "NO" will only be returned in the case that "YES" is not returned.

Comment: The `else` there after a `return` under the `if` is rather redundant.  `if (c.empty())
    return "YES";
return "NO";`